# I get unlimited amount of GET 404 Error if I try to setState in axios catch error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to setState inside a catch promise in Axios React, It works but I get an unlimited amount of request and 404 error.

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    notFound: false,
    dataResult: "",
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    axios
      .get("url")
      .then((resp) => {
        this.setState({ dataResult: resp.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response.status === 404) {
          this.setState({ notFound: true });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.notFound ? <div>NOTFOUND</div> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

console result(URL is an API):

GET "url" 404 (Not Found)
GET "url" 404 (Not Found)
GET "url" 404 (Not Found)
...

Comment: Use `componentDidMount` function instead of `componentDidUpdate` to avoid infinite calls.

Comment: @PrakashSharma I need to fetch data when my input state get updated.

Comment: Then wrap that call in condition so that it only gets called when input state get updated and not everytime.

Comment: @PrakashSharma How can I check if the state is updated without using ```componentDidUpdate``` ?

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to call axios, on some input state change then you need to wrap that call with some condition so that it only gets called when input state actually changes. `componentDidUpdate` method is invoked with previous state object. So you can compare previous state with current state to make sure that the state is actually changed.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState.myInputState !== this.state.myInputState) {
    axios
      .get("url")
      .then((resp) => {
        this.setState({ dataResult: resp.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response.status === 404) {
          this.setState({ notFound: true });
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note
> that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or
> you’ll cause an infinite loop.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.url !== prevProps.url) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```